# jquery side without resizing element

Tags: jquery, css, layout, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu using css columns, and when I use `jquery slide()`, it resizes the drowdown box, and reflows the contents untill full height is acheived.

Here is a working example
https://codepen.io/petergus/pen/dvrrGj

Is there an alternative that would simply slide down and reveal the already sized element (which are waiting in the display:none state)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your `ul.sub-menu` elements in another container, then resize that instead:

```
  <ul>
    <li class="sub-menu-parent">
      <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
      <div class="sub-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

This will require refactoring your CSS to accommodate the change. To start with:

```
nav {
  position: relative;
}

nav > ul > li > .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu ul {
  columns: 5;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/mblase75/pen/bqZJbg